# Jest functional/ unit test serve assets from public folder

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

My react functional component returns viewers from the third-party npm package.
which renders another SPA in the iframe, all the assets required for that SPA are in my public folder.
While unit testing these assets are not getting accessed.
how to serve this asset from the public folder.

the iframe render in test screen look like bellow

```
<iframe
      id="webviewer-1"
      src="js/pdftron/./ui/index.html#d=%22%2Ftest%2Fdocument.pdf%22&amp;extension=pdf&amp;a=1&amp;css=%2Fpublicjs%2Fpdftron%2FPDFTronCustomStyle.css&amp;user=undefined undefined&amp;filepicker=0&amp;pdfnet=0&amp;enableRedaction=0&amp;disableVirtualDisplayMode=0&amp;enableMeasurement=0&amp;pageHistory=1&amp;notesInLeftPanel=0&amp;autoExpandOutlines=0&amp;enableAnnotationNumbering=0&amp;forceClientSideInit=1&amp;singleServerMode=false&amp;selectAnnotationOnCreation=0&amp;autoFocusNoteOnAnnotationSelection=1&amp;id=1&amp;basePath=%2F&amp;webViewerJSVersion=8.11.0"
      title="webviewer"
      frameborder="0"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      allowfullscreen="true"
      webkitallowfullscreen="true"
      mozallowfullscreen="true"
    ></iframe><
```

My public(folder for public assets) folder contains js/pdftron folder which has all the required assets.